# Implementing / forcing SSL for LocomotiveJS apps (NodeJS / Express)

Tags: node.js, ssl, locomotivejs

With MVC frameworks like [LocomotiveJS](http://locomotivejs.org) now available for NodeJS / Express, I'm just wondering how it would be possible to implement SSL on part of an app?

For example, an ecommerce app.

I'd need all /checkout controllers to force SSL.

I've read tutorials like [this one](http://elias.kg/post/14971446990/force-ssl-with-express-js-on-heroku-nginx) but not sure on how to implement this with Locomotive, since Express is effectively "wrapped" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently SSL is not directly supported by Locomotive, but should be soon, according to [this Google Groups posting in April](https://groups.google.com/group/locomotivejs/tree/browse_frm/month/2012-04/7b66b30f2a863a50?rnum=1&_done=/group/locomotivejs/browse_frm/month/2012-04?#doc_ccf6ba08009c4e75) by Jared Hanson, the creator of Locomotive.

> Currently, I've always been putting Locomotive behind a proxy that 
>   terminates SSL.  But, I'll be adding a command line option for this 
>   shortly, for direct support.

That said, if you want a completely node-based solution without using a proxy, then for the time being you'll need to edit the Express instance in Locomotive. I've tested the below and it's working well.

As of writing, `npm install locomotive` uses Express 2.x, though the latest at github has since been updated to use Express 3.x.

If you're using Locomotive with Express 2.x, then I think you have to edit `/locomotive/lib/locomotive/index.js`, around line 180, to look something like:

```
var sslOptions = {
    cert : fs.readFileSync('/path/to/your/ssl-cert/dev.crt')
  , key  : fs.readFileSync('/path/to/your/ssl-key/dev.key')
};

var self = this
  , server = express.createServer(sslOptions)
  , entry;
```

Additionally, you will probably still want to listen on HTTP and redirect all traffic to HTTPS. Sticking with an all node-based solution, you could simply start another Express server at the end of `/locomotive/lib/locomotive/cli/server.js` that redirects all its traffic to HTTPS, e.g.

```
    ...
    debug('booting app at %s in %s environment', dir, env);
    locomotive.boot(dir, env, function(err, server) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    server.listen(port, address, function() {
      var addr = this.address();
      debug('listening on %s:%d', addr.address, addr.port);
    });

    // add an http server and redirect all request to https
    var httpServer = require('express').createServer();
    httpServer.all('*', function(req, res) {
      res.redirect('https://' + address + ':' + port + req.url);
    });
    httpServer.listen(80); // probably change based on NODE_ENV
  });
}
```

Lastly, start the server:

```
$ lcm server -p 443 # again, probably use different port in development
```

Answer (score 0):

All those frameworks are based on top of Express which based is on connect which has HTTPS support.

Anyway in a real life situation you might want to want to have a nginx/or nother proxy handling the https for you anyway.